# I can't filter results of a Yajara Datatable in front end of a date range (client side)

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, datatable

I'm tryng to filter a date field between two dates, but this dont work, for some reason the ajax run, but dont change de recordsFiltered, my  code is bellow:

AJAX

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function(settings, data, dataIndex) {var min = $("#b_datac_inicio").val();var max =  $("#b_datac_fim").val();var date = data[6]; // A coluna "date" é a sétima coluna (índice 6)
```

```
  // Verifica se a data está dentro do intervalo de data especificado pelo usuário
  if (min == "" && max == "") {
     return true;
  }
  if (min == "" && date <= max) {
     return true;
  }
  if (max == "" && date >= min) {
     return true;
  }
  if (date <= max && date >= min) {
     return true;
  }
  return false;
```

```
});
```

```
$('#b_datac_inicio, #b_datac_fim').change( function() {
```

```
         table.draw();
 });`
```

PHP / HTML

```
                            <input type="date" id="b_datac_inicio" class="form-control form-control-sm filter-input" placeholder="Digite o periodo" data-column="0" />
                      
                            <input type="date" id="b_datac_fim" class="form-control form-control-sm filter-input" placeholder="Digite o periodo" data-column="0" />
```

RESULT OF AJAX (Lan tab of developer options on brownser)

```
{draw: 7, recordsTotal: 102, recordsFiltered: 102, data: [,…], input: {draw: "7",…}} data :  [,…] 0 :  {id: 148, user_cad_id: 1, grupo_cad_id: 2, grupo_cad_nome: "Coodenação de Int",…} 1 :  {id: 147, user_cad_id: 1, grupo_cad_id: 3, grupo_cad_nome: "PRxxxx", user_cad_name: "Admin",…} 2 :  {id: 146, user_cad_id: 1, grupo_cad_id: 2, grupo_cad_nome: "Coodenação de Int",…} 3 :  {id: 145, user_cad_id: 1, grupo_cad_id: 3, grupo_cad_nome: "PRxxxx", user_cad_name: "Admin",…} 4 :  {id: 144, user_cad_id: 1, grupo_cad_id: 3, grupo_cad_nome: "PRxxxx", user_cad_name: "Admin",…} 5 :  {id: 143, user_cad_id: 1, grupo_cad_id: 3, grupo_cad_nome: "PRxxxx", user_cad_name: "Admin",…} 6 :  {id: 142, user_cad_id: 1, grupo_cad_id: 3, grupo_cad_nome: "PRxxxx", user_cad_name: "Admin",…} 7 :  {id: 141, user_cad_id: 1, grupo_cad_id: 3, grupo_cad_nome: "PRxxxx", user_cad_name: "Admin",…} 8 :  {id: 140, user_cad_id: 1, grupo_cad_id: 3, grupo_cad_nome: "PRxxxx", user_cad_name: "Admin",…} 9 :  {id: 139, user_cad_id: 1, grupo_cad_id: 3, grupo_cad_nome: "PRxxxx", user_cad_name: "Admin",…} draw :  7 input :  {draw: "7",…} recordsFiltered :  102 recordsTotal :  102
```

I expect that after the "processing" the listed itens of my index change, also the number of total records and showing itens X to XX.

Comment: Did you check the `console` tab of your browser? It's a client-side action, should be no network activity to filter those records

Comment: I say that is a cliente side action, but this results in a ajax calling, because of that has network activity. (i dont implement in the controller).